# Polymorphic associations and/or has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create relationships between a user, product and a photo-model. A user can add photos to a product. Therefore, a user `has_many` photos and a product `has_many` photos, but each photo `belongs_to` both a product and a user. How can I achieve this in Rails? As far as I understand a polymorphic association would only allow a photo to belong to a product or a user. Do I have to instead using separate `has_many_through` relationships for the user-photo and product-photo relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple belongs_to attributes within the same model.  Essentially the Model that is marked as belongs_to will hold a foreign key to the Model that has been marked with has_many.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :other_model1
  belongs_to :other_model2

end
```

If you want to use polymorphic associates as you mentioned below you could do that along these lines

```
class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :imageable
end
```

In this case you can create the relationship simply by adding the has_many :phots, :as => :imageable attribute without having to revisit the Photos class.